# Could you explain why there is a transpose in this proof? (Invariance of distances with linear transformation)

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra

The equation is supposed to be
$$s^2 = \eta_{\mu \nu} \Delta x^\mu \Delta x^\nu.$$

How is it transformed to,

$$s^2 = (\Delta x)^T\eta (\Delta x) = (\Delta x')^T\eta (\Delta x')~? $$

Why is there a transpose here? How is the rearrangement equal to the initial equation?

This is from Caroll's lecture notes on General Relativity, eqn. 1.13

Answer (score 1):

If you have an $N$-by$N$ matrix you can matrix-multiply in an $N$ component column vector from the right,  but you can only matrix-multiply in an $N$ component *row* vector from the left. Left matrix-multiplying by an $N$-component column vector is incompatable. The transpose is to convert the column vector to a row vector:
$$
x_\mu M_{\mu\nu} x_\nu = {\bf x}^T {\bf M} {\bf x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Because thats how matrix multiplication works. Everything that appears on the right hand side, $\eta_{\mu \nu}$, $\Delta x^\mu$, are components (which are numbers) of some object so they can be moved around. So $s^2=\eta_{\mu \nu}\Delta x^\mu\Delta x^\nu=\Delta x^\mu\eta_{\mu \nu}\Delta x^\nu$. Since $\Delta x^\mu$ is contracted with the first index of
$\eta _{\mu\nu}$
, the rule for matrix multiplication says that the contraction gets the $\nu$th component of $$(\Delta x)^T\eta=\begin{bmatrix}
 \Delta x^0 & \Delta x^1 & \Delta x^2 &\Delta x^3
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 \eta_{00} & \eta_{01} & \eta_{02} & \eta_{03}\\
 \eta_{10} & \eta_{11} &\eta_{12}  & \eta_{13}\\
 \eta_{20} & \eta_{21} & \eta_{22} & \eta_{23}\\
 \eta_{30} & \eta_{31} & \eta_{32} &\eta_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$$ It makes no sense to multiply the column vector $\Delta x$ on the left.